# STL efficiency when using big objects

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

To be more specific let's restrict the scope of the question to libstdc++ and Visual C++.

Consider the case when objects stored in a container have the following properties:

- Copying and assignment can be expensive
- Moving and swapping is cheap and never throws
- Default constructor is cheap and never throws

Some of the containers may and will reallocate/move stored objects when elements are added or removed. In that case do the above mentioned STL implementations avoid copying when reallocating/moving elements?

What about *std::sort* and other algorithms?

If you think about it there is no need for copying when moving and swapping is available.

As you may know all STL operation provide *Big O* complexity guaranties. B*ig O* means there is constant multiplied by some function of *N*. My question could be paraphrased by asking what does that constant include? Does it include the cost of copying or it is proportional to the cost of moving/swapping?

Thanks you.

Comment: Each algorithm specifies its big-O guarantees in terms of some operation or other.  Asking about the entire STL, the most you can hope for is "sure, it is good, don't worry about it": specifics are going to be specific to each function, and there are lots of functions.

Comment: Typically for large objects you use STL with some smart pointers to the objects

Comment: How are you getting Visual C++ to use libstdc++?

Comment: @ Yakk. You didn't understand the question. Big-O specified in terms of number of elements and some multiplier. The multiplier is constant, that is it doesn't depend on number of elements.

Comment: @ Alan Stokes. libstdc++ used with GCC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only general answer that can be given is that C++ is made by smart people that care a lot about performance so you usually won't find easy optimizations missed out and shouldn't worry too much about your standard library's performance.

You can answer these question type-by-type and function-by-function by reading the specification in the standard, websites like [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com) or the documentation that comes with your implementation.  For example, if `std::vector::push_back` has to re-allocate its internal buffer, it will use the move constructor to “copy” over the elements if and only if such constructor exists and is declared `noexcept` (also see [`std::move_if_noexcept`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move_if_noexcept)).

A different approach to reason about what is *actually* going on inside your standard library is taking it for a test drive.  Instrument a simple `struct` to print out logging messages from its constructors and assignment operators, then put instances of that class into a standard library container and exercise some algorithm on it.  The following example uses `std::vector` and `std::sort`.  You can play with it by using different containers and algorithms.  Also see what's happening if you make the changes indicated by the comments.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>


struct Example
{

  int id;

  Example(const int id) : id {id}
  {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  }

  Example(const Example& rhs) : id {rhs.id}
  {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  }

  // try commenting out the 'noexcept'
  Example(Example&& rhs) noexcept : id {rhs.id}
  {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  }

  Example&
  operator=(const Example& rhs)
  {
    this->id = rhs.id;
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    return *this;
  }

  // try commenting out the 'noexcept'
  Example&
  operator=(Example&& rhs) noexcept
  {
    this->id = rhs.id;
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    return *this;
  }

  ~Example() noexcept
  {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  }

};


int
main()
{
  const auto n = 10;
  auto rndeng = std::default_random_engine {};
  auto rnddst = std::uniform_int_distribution<int> {};
  auto elements = std::vector<Example> {};
  std::cout << "CONSTRUCTING VECTOR OF " << n << " ELEMENTS...\n\n";
  elements.reserve(n);  // try commenting this out
  for (auto i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    elements.emplace_back(rnddst(rndeng));  // try using push_back instead
  const auto cmp = [](const Example& lhs, const Example& rhs){
    return lhs.id < rhs.id;
  };
  std::cout << "\nSORTING ELEMENTS...\n\n";
  std::sort(elements.begin(), elements.end(), cmp);
  std::cout << "\nSORTED ELEMENTS:\n\n";
  for (const auto& elem : elements)
    std::cout << std::setw(16) << elem.id << "\n";
  std::cout << "\nLEAVING MAIN...\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Looks like Visual C++ takes advantage of move semantics. Didn't test libstdc++ yet.